# Exploit vulnerabilty in embedded Linux network stack to disable iptables

Tags: network, linux, iptables

I own a `D-Link DCS-7110` HD POE network camera.

It features an apparently `iptables` based access list configuration where you can allow/disallow certain networks and addresses from accessing the camera.

I accidentally disabled access for everyone, thus can not acces it at all anymore. It boots, get's an ip-address from my dhcp and just sits there, shielded from the outside world.

I have already tried changing my dhcp server to provide an address from a different network, in the hope I had just disabled access for my own network, but it seems I disabled it for all networks. Good job.

Unfortunately the camera is installed about 10m over ground and I can not easily access it at all.

I have not found information about a known vulnerability in the network stack of the firmware, but I wonder if there would be one which could allow me to exploit to disable `iptables` and get access to it again.

I managed to extract the firmware binary, but have not spent much time analyzing it. It seems to use a Linux kernel 2.6.

Does anyone have an idea on how to proceed? Otherwise I should prepare myself to rent a cherry picker to be able to reach the camera and do a factory reset.

Comment: I think you're just gonna have to break out a ladder.

Comment: As @RoraΖ stated, it will be really faster and more effective to just get the ladder up and access the camera physically.

Comment: iptables is practically bullet proof at this point. It's such a small and low level bit of software that the attack surface is small and it filters everything before any of software can see it so even if the camera had a magic switch that you could throw a single packet at to disable the filtering you wouldn't be able to do anything.

Comment: Even if there is an extant networking vulnerability in the kernel version you are using (which there very well may be), actually writing a working exploit takes a lot of time and effort. You'll end up wanting to use a ladder, regardless of whether or not the networking stack is vulnerable.